# Problem with uploading files with filezilla

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, nginx

I'm running a nginx server on ubuntu server 12.04.3 LTS but unfortunately I'm not being able to upload files with filezilla to it. I am able to open and browse the machine with filezilla but whenever I try to upload something I get the following message error `...open for write: permission denied`. Any ideia on how to solve this? My server is encrypted lvm but I don't know what else should suit you to help me...

Comment: What protocol are you using in Filezilla to connect to the server? Is it SFTP? If it is, then you will log in to the server as a particular user, and hence will create files as that logged in user, and so that user must have write permission on the directory where you are creating the file.

Comment: @DavidPurdue SFTP exacly! And how should I do that?

Comment: To which directories do you want to upload your files?

Comment: @quntbert to the following /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php: open for write: permission denied

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: @quntbert better late than never eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a test-directory and chmod this so everyone can read and write in it.

```
mkdir test 
chmod 777 test
```

Now you put a file in it with ftp and look what user and group needs access.

```
cd test
ls -l
```

Once you know username and group you either have to change ownership of the directories in which you want your ftp users to write or you can make the ftpuser part of the group who owns the directories.

```
chown :ftpgroup dir_to_write (you can add -R for recursive but do not do this on system dirs!)
```

or:

```
adduser ftpuser group_who_owns_directory
```

If you only want to write to the html dir I would probably add the ftpuser to the html group so you do not get conflicts between the different processes on ownership.

Comment: I actually just had to log in as root :p now I updated the permissions correctly to the user. Thank you very much!